# Is there any image morphing software with a command-line interface?

Tags: command-line

I'm searching for image morphing software that can be accessed from the command line, because I want to write a shell script that will morph one image into another image. Specifically, I'd like to be able to enter a series of images into the command line, and produce a morphing image animation. Does any software with this capability currently exist?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you want one image to fade into another, or do you want *interpolation* between the initial and target image?

Comment: @InkBlend I'm talking about interpolation between the two images. This is what xmorph is intended for.

Answer (score 4):

After a bit of searching, I found a command-line image morphing program called [xmorph](http://xmorph.sourceforge.net/home/gourlay/public_html/Xmorph/pub/examples/Tutorial/) (which is based on the libmorph image morphing library.) It is currently available for Windows and Linux, and it also has a graphical user interface. It can generate a series of images to represent an image morphing animation (based on a source image and a target image), but you'll need to use another program to convert the series of images to a video or animated GIF format.

Comment: There's a tutorial for xmorph available here: http://xmorph.sourceforge.net/home/gourlay/public_html/Xmorph/pub/examples/Tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this: https://pypi.org/project/facemorpher/.

This does what the OP asked for:

```
python facemorpher/morpher.py --images=/path/to/images --out_video=output.avi
```

This creates an average image out of a set of images:

```
python facemorpher/averager.py --images=/path/to/images --background=average --out=output.png
mogrify -channel rgb -negate output.png
```

For some reason the output image uses negative colors when `--background=average` is specified.

Sample output (average of 10 images):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), a command-line tool which allows for all sorts of image manipulations, including a number of operations listed under 'morphology' - You might look to see if that will suit your needs.

Comment: 'morphology', as described here: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/, does not appear to be intended for motion tweening, but for other types of image transformations (such as pixel erosion).

Answer (score 0):

I have written a tool that doesn't require setting manual keypoints and is not restricted to a domain (like faces). Anyway, the images have to be similar (e.g. two faces or two cars from the same perspective). It's still a work in progress but already works great!

https://github.com/kallaballa/Poppy

[Image Morphing Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYvy4.gif)

example usage:
`poppy -o video.mp4 image1.png image2.png`